# get distinct rows between two lists

Tags: c#

I have this code here which i use to find the differt rows between two lists and add them to another one like below;

```
List<xml.DatabaseDescriptor> dbDesc = _dbDesc.ToList();
foreach (xml.DatabaseDescriptor desc1 in dbDesc)
{
    foreach (xml.DatabaseDescriptor desc2 in xmlData.Databases)
    {
        if (desc1.Name != desc2.Name)
        {
            xmlData.Databases.Add(
                new xml.DatabaseDescriptor() {
                    DatabaseName = desc1.Name, Tables = newTable
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error though.
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

How do i fix it, i tried the Except to get the difference between both lists and didn't work.

Comment: `...and add them to another one` There is no *another one* list in your code.

Comment: Even if you fix this problem, you have another one: This will create up to `dbDesc.Count * xmlData.Databases.Count` items!

Comment: I provided a Custom Comparer which uses the Name field, give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a collection you're iterating on.

You should iterate on a copy of `xmlData.Databases` if you want to modify the original one.

Also you should be able to use LINQ with a Custom Comparer to obtain the difference of the two lists and then add it to the first one.

```
class DatabaseDescriptorComparer : IEqualityComparer<DatabaseDescriptor>
{
    public bool Equals(DatabaseDescriptor x, DatabaseDescriptor y)
    {
        return
            x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DatabaseDescriptor obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
var toAdd = dbDesc.Except(xmlData, new DatabaseDescriptorComparer() ).ToList();
foreach(var x in toAdd){
    xmlData.Databases.Add(
        new xml.DatabaseDescriptor() { DatabaseName = x.Name, Tables = newTable }
    );
}
```

Comment: Good idea using `Except` but it won't work based on OPs criteria (Name attribute different) - unless you use a custom comparer

Comment: Provided also the comparer in the answer

Comment: Use `obj.Name.GetHashCode();` in order to be consistent with `Equals`.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply, here i get this error in the toAdd: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceConfig.xml.DatabaseDescriptor>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ServiceConfig.xml.DatabaseDescriptor>

Answer (score 0):

First create a union of both enumerations and then take unique descriptors by unsing a compararer that compares decriptor names:

```
List<DatabaseDescriptor> result = _dbDesc
    .Union(xmlData.Databases)
    .Distinct(DatabaseDescriptorNameComparer.Instance)
    .ToList();
```

I am using the singleton pattern for this comparer:

```
class DatabaseDescriptorNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<DatabaseDescriptor>
{
    public static readonly DatabaseDescriptorNameComparer Instance =
        new DatabaseDescriptorNameComparer();

    private DatabaseDescriptorNameComparer()
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(DatabaseDescriptor x, DatabaseDescriptor y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DatabaseDescriptor obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't work, the result list still doesn't give me the unique rows from both lists..

Comment: Why not? Waht happens?